# Cross-platform analogue of Mempad text editor

Tags: text-editor, cross-platform, note-taking

[Mempad](http://www.horstmuc.de/wmem.htm) is a windows-based text editor with a couple of handy features I use it for. These include:

1. A tree-oriented note structure which allows for a high degree of organization of ideas & topics.
2. An auto-save feature which periodically saves notes to disc without requiring the user to manually do so.

When all the machines I regularly used both professionally & personally were Windows systems, it was handy to store and update a mempad lst file (their delimited text files) within dropbox through the day with notes & tasks.

Now I have a Mac computer at work, and am hoping there is either a Mac analogue for opening & editing these files or that there is a cross-platform solution which can work for both OS'es.